How can I get the probability of three random variables satisfying equations containing sums and functions of the variables
Consider three independent random variables, X, Y and Z. The cdf and pdf of these are known to be $F_{X}(x)$,  $F_{Y}(y)$,  $F_{Z}(z)$ and  $f_{X}(x)$,  $f_{Y}(y)$,  $f_{Z}(z)$. X and Y are positivie real numbers, and Z is a real number.
I want to calculate the probability of a draw of the three variables meeting a set of conditions. The first condition is that the values of X and Y drawn are such that both values of X and Y are contained within the line $Y \le -a X^2 + c$, with both $a \ge0, c\ge0$. i.e. if we plot the value of X and Y on a 2-dimensional graph (weakly positive values for both variable only), the values drawn are bounded by the curve described above and the graph axes.
The second condition is that $k - e \le (dX)^{b} + Z \le k + e$, for some positive values b, d, e and k.
I would like to find the probability of these two things occurring on one random draw of these three variables.
To attempt this problem I began by tackling each condition separately. For the first I do the integration:
$$
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{c/a}} \int_{0}^{c - ax^2} f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(t) dt dx
$$
to get the area probability of the draws laying within the curve. For the second part, I rewrite the pdf of $U = (dX)^{b}$ as $f_{U}(u) = f_{X}({1\over a}u^{{1 \over b}})({1\over ab}u^{{1-b \over b}})$. Then we can use the convolution of $f_{U}(u)$,  $f_{Z}(z)$ to find the pdf of $V = U + Z$ as
$$
f_{V}(v) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_{U}(w) f_{Z}(v - w) dw
$$
From there, we can find $Pr(k -e \le V \le k + e) = \int_{k-e}^{k+e} f_V(v) dv$.
However, as variable X occurs in both parts of the condition, I am not sure how to treat it. One way I have considered is finding the conditional pdf $f_{X|A}(x)$, where A implies the inequality $k - e \le (dX)^{b} + Z \le k + e$ holds. From there I would use this conditional pdf and the pdf of Y to find the area beneath the curve, which would give to total probability. I am unsure how to proceed with this from forming the conditional probability.
In practical terms, I am considering the X,Y to be drawn from (different) lognormal distributions, and Z from a normal distribution.
Thank you for any and all help!

You can use one triple integral to meet all the conditions simultaneously.

Could you explain how you would do this? Would it simply be $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{c/a}} \int_{0}^{c - a x^{2}} \int_{k - e - (dx)^{2}}^{k + e - (dx)^{2}} f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(t) f_{Z}(z) dz dt dx$

Yes, that's exactly it.
